# Ansible: variable is defined but error shows not defined

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook as follows:

```
---
- name: test variables
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: test
    command: echo {{ ansible_role_dir }}
    register: result
  - name: show result
    debug:
      msg="{{ result.stdout }}"

  #roles:  #line12
  #  - "{{ ansible_role_dir }}/testrole" #line13
```

the variable ansible_role_dir is defined under group_vars/all.yaml.

if I run the playbook which comments out the line12 and line13, it shows the result of variable correctly. Obviously it knows where the variable ansible_role_dir is defined. But if I uncomment line12 and line13, it shows error `ERROR! 'ansible_role_dir' is undefined`. Why it does not know where the ansible_role_dir is defined this time?

Comment: The `group_vars/all` stuff assigns variables to the hosts.  The parser does not know about any hosts yet, it's just trying to parse the playbook.  The `roles_path` variable should be set in `ansible.cfg` to do what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Jack, can you give more details? the `command: echo {{ ansible_role_dir }}` can be executed if line12 and line13 are commented out, which means the parser know {{ ansible_role_dir}}

Comment: The PARSER does not know `ansible_role_dir`, no.  The variable substitution in `command: echo {{ ansible_role_dir }}` is done at RUN-time, using the variable for each individual host.  It might work if, instead of `roles`, you have the task `- include_role: "{{ ansible_role_dir }}/testrole"`.  But why?  Do you have a different `testrole` for different hosts?

Comment: `testrole` is the name of your role. You don't need anything else to reference it unless you have some specific and non standard setup/directory architecture. The only way to have the above example working would be to set the var as an extra_var directly on the command line. You do not want that. If your you have non standard paths for your roles (i.e. your home dir `.ansible` folder and the `roles` folder adjacent to your playbook), just set that in ansible.cfg (either globally or in your project).

Comment: ok, will not use this way, will configure role_path in ansible.cfg then. Thanks Jack and Zeitounator

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does not like jinja tags without quotes. try this:

```
---
- name: test variables
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: test
    command: "echo {{ ansible_role_dir }}"
    register: result
  - name: show result
    debug:
      msg="{{ result.stdout }}"

  #roles:  #line12
  #  - "{{ ansible_role_dir }}/testrole" #line13
```

EDIT:
sorry, i think i misread the question.

have you tried putting in the real path instead of the var, just to see if it works? usually role paths are given in ansible's config, i never saw them run with a direct path

Comment: Thanks Ehud: putting real path works. i.e. change line13 to - ../../logrotate/roles/logrotate works

Comment: Although systematically quoting strings containing jinja2 markers is IMO a good practice, it is only mandatory in ansible if the given string begins with a moustache (curly brace) character. In recent versions, ansible will raise an error in such cases anyway.

Comment: thanks, @Zeitounator, i learn new things every day :). never thought to re-test those errors.

user389955 - the other thing i can think of is that something between your inline tasks and the role call below funks up things. i would look at the role's defaults dir, vars dir and the main.yml tasks file.

Comment: ok, will not use this way, will configure role_path in ansible.cfg then. Thanks Ehud